# Play Framework Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in controller

Tags: dependency-injection, playframework, guice, playframework-2.6

Play 2.6.6, Scala 2.12.3. I'm using a [library](https://github.com/t2v/play2-auth) to implement authentication

The full error is:

```
ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jp.t2v.lab.play2.stackc.StackableController.$init$(Ljp/t2v/lab/play2/stackc/StackableController;)
```

The controller that is causing the error is implemented like this:

`class AuthController @Inject() (override val accountsTable: Accounts) extends Controller with AuthElement with AuthConfigImpl {`

`StackableController` is used in the `AuthElement` trait as follows:

`trait AuthElement extends StackableController with AsyncAuth {`

which is itself a trait.

I cannot figure out why the DI system is failing on this piece of the library. This code has worked previously for me, but it was a Play 2.4.x project

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a Play 2.4 module within a Play 2.6 project. APIs have changed, which is indicated by the minor version bump. The play2-auth module seems to be unmaintained for some while, at least there is a PR for Play 2.6 support: https://github.com/t2v/play2-auth/pull/191 ...